# Hadoop - sqoop Export/Import Partitioned table

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Can anyone explain how to export partitioned table from hive to MYSQL database?

And how to import into a hive partitioned table from mysql?

I have read the documents in google but not sure on the latest techniques that can be used.

Thanks

Comment: Did you checked out Sqoop documentation?
For reference :- https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### sqoop to hive partition import

#### 1. create a table in mysql with 4 fields (id, name, age, sex)

```
CREATE TABLE `mon2`
(`id` int, `name` varchar(43), `age` int, `sex` varchar(334))
```

#### 2. insert data into mysql table using csv **abc.csv**

```
1,mahesh,23,m
2,ramesh,32,m
3,prerna,43,f
4,jitu,23,m
5,sandip,32,m
6,gps,43,f
```

`mysql> source location_of_your_csv/abc.csv`

#### 3. now start your hadoop service and goto $SQOOP_HOME and write sqoop import query for partition hive import.

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apr \
--username root \
--password root \
-e "select id, name, age from mon2 where sex='m' and \$CONDITIONS" \
--target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/hive_part \
--split-by id \
--hive-overwrite \
--hive-import \
--create-hive-table \
--hive-partition-key sex \
--hive-partition-value 'm' \
--fields-terminated-by ',' \
--hive-table mar.hive_part \
--direct
```

### hive to sqoop export with partition

#### 1. create hive_temp table for load data

```
create table hive_temp
(id int, name string, age int, gender string)
row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

#### 2. load data

```
load data local inpath '/home/zicone/Documents/pig_to_hbase/stack.csv' into table hive_temp;
```

#### 3. create a partition table with a specific column that you want to partition.

```
create table hive_part1
(id int, name string, age int)
partitioned by (gender string)
row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

#### 4. add a partition in hive_temp table

```
alter table hive_part1 add partition(gender='m');
```

#### 5. copy data from temp to hive_part table

```
insert overwrite table hive_part1 partition(gender='m')
select id, name, age from hive_temp where gender='m';
```

#### 6. sqoop export command

create a table in mysql

`mysql> create table mon3 like mon2;`

```
sqoop export \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apr \
--table mon3 \
--export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/mar.db/hive_part1/gender=m \
-m 1 \
--username root \
--password root
```

now goto mysql terminal and run

```
select * from mon3;
```

hope it works for you
:)

Comment: this is really helpful for new guys of sqoop(hadoop) import/export.

thanks mahesh

Comment: After sqoop exporting to mysql, the `sex` (`gender`) field will be missing (as null) . sqoop version: `1.4.6-cdh5.9.0`

Comment: @maheshgupta Exactly the same as listed in `6. sqoop export command`.  Only the columns `id`,`name`, and `age` will be exported to the destination table.  As a solution, I duplicated the column for partition key(`create table hive_part1
(id int, name string, age int, gender string)
partitioned by (g string)`) . FYI.

Comment: @AlphaTAN Have you created MySQL Table same as Hive Partition Table?

Comment: @maheshgupta Sure.

Comment: Can we export data from hive bucketed table using sqoop export?

Comment: @vikrantrana 
Sqoop with hcatalog does not work with bucketed hive table as this is not supported yet. ( import or export)

Comment: @maheshgupta Thanks for wonderful example. So sqoop export on bucketing tables not possible at any way? I know that by converting non bucketing tables we can do. Can you suggest if there is a way to do directly export?

Comment: @TharunkumarReddy i am glad you are getting help from my answer.  so for now exporting bucket table directly not supported. only way to achieve that.. you have mentioned above.

Comment: @ArunS can you please accept this answer if its solve your problem.thanks